# What does pairs() or ipairs() do in Lua?

Tags: lua

Programming beginner here learning Lua. I always see this function in example code mostly in a for loop that goes through an array. I dont actually understand what it does and why I should use it. It seems I make similar for loops a lot that do almost the same thing but i never use pairs() or ipairs()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference of pairs() vs. ipairs() in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108794/what-is-the-difference-of-pairs-vs-ipairs-in-lua)

Comment: I suggest you read https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html

Comment: "It seems I ...never use pairs() or ipairs()"  Yeah, you don't have to use them, they're convenience functions.

Answer (score 2):

From the Lua 5.4 Reference manual:

> #### ipairs (t)
>
> Returns three values (an iterator function, the table t, and 0) so
> that the construction
>
> ```
>  for i,v in ipairs(t) do body end
> ```
>
> will iterate over the key–value pairs (1,t[1]), (2,t[2]), ..., up to
> the first absent index.
>
> #### pairs (t)
>
> If t has a metamethod __pairs, calls it with t as argument and returns
> the first three results from the call.
>
> Otherwise, returns three values: the next function, the table t, and
> nil, so that the construction
>
> ```
>  for k,v in pairs(t) do body end
> ```
>
> will iterate over all key–value pairs of table t.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-ipairs

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pairs