# What's the proper way to find the last parcel of an array?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm doing some codewars and `arr[index]` keeps returning `nil`. I've done this a few different ways, and I'm sure the array exists, as well as the index. What's wrong here, is it syntax?
As I've mentioned in the title, I want to find the last digit of the array.

```lua
if arr[index] <= 0 then
    return -1
end
```

Full Code:

```lua
local solution = {}

function solution.newAvg(arr, navg)
    local currentAverage = 0
    local index = 0
    for i, v in pairs(arr) do
        index = i
        currentAverage = currentAverage + v
    end
    if arr[index] <= 0 then
        return -1
    end
    return math.ceil(((index+1) * navg) - currentAverage)
end

return solution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your code:

## Edge case: Empty array

If `arr = {}`, the loop `for i, v in pairs(arr) do` won't execute at all and `index` will remain at `0`. Since `arr` is empty, `arr[0]` will be `nil` and `arr[index] <= 0` will fail with an "attempt to compare a nil value" error.

## Lack of ordering guarantee

You use `pairs` rather than `ipairs` to loop over what I assume is a list. This means keys & values might be traversed in any order. In practice `pairs` usually (but not always!) traverses the list part of a table in the same order as `ipairs`, but the reference manual clearly states that you can't rely on no specific order. I don't think CodeWars is this advanced but consider the possibility that `pairs` may be overridden to deliberately shuffle the order of traversal in order to check whether you're relying on the dreaded "undefined behavior". If this is the case, your "last index" might actually be any index that happens to be visited last, obviously breaking your algorithm.

## Fixes

I'll assume `arr` is an "array", that is, it only contains keys from `1` to `n` and all values are non-`nil` (i.e. there are no holes). Then you can (and should!) use `ipairs` to loop over the "array":

```lua
for i, v in ipairs(arr) do ... end
```

I don't know the problem statement so it's hard to tell how an empty array should be handled. I'll assume that it should probably return `0`. You could add a simply early return at the top of the function for that: `if arr[1] == nil then return 0 end`. Nonempty arrays will always have `arr[1] ~= nil`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find the last digit of the array.

If you mean the last integer (or entry/item) of the array:

```lua
local last = array[#array]
```

If you mean the last digit (for example `array = {10, 75, 44, 62}` and you want `2`), then you can get the last item and then get the last digit using modulo 10:

```lua
local last = array[#array] % 10
```

> ```lua
> for i, v in pairs(arr) do
>     index = i
>     currentAverage = currentAverage + v
> end
> ```

Just a reminder:

1. `#array` returns the number of items in a table.
2. In Lua, arrays are implemented using integer-indexed tables.
3. There's a [difference between `pairs()` and `ipairs()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55109411/16835308).

Regarding point 3 above, the following code:

```lua
local array = {
    [1] = 12,
    [2] = 32,
    [3] = 41,
    [4] = 30,
    [5] = 14,
    [6] = 50,
    [7] = 62,
    [8] = 57
}

for key, value in pairs(array) do
    print(key, value)
end
```

produces the following output (note that the order of keys is not respected):

```
8   57
1   12
2   32
3   41
4   30
5   14
6   50
7   62
```

while the same code above with `pairs()` replaced with `ipairs()` gives:

```
1   12
2   32
3   41
4   30
5   14
6   50
7   62
8   57
```

So, this might be the cause of your problem.